# Is there a LINQ extension or (a sensible/efficient set of LINQ entensions) that determine whether a collection has at least 'x' elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumeration, performance

I have code that needs to know that a collection should not be empty or contain only one item.

In general, I want an extension of the form:

`bool collectionHasAtLeast2Items = collection.AtLeast(2);`

I can write an extension easily, enumerating over the collection and incrementing an indexer until I hit the requested size, or run out of elements, but is there something already in the LINQ framework that would do this?  My thoughts (in order of what came to me) are::

`bool collectionHasAtLeast2Items = collection.Take(2).Count() == 2;` or

`bool collectionHasAtLeast2Items = collection.Take(2).ToList().Count == 2;`

Which would seem to work, though the behaviour of taking more elements than the collection contains is not defined (in the documentation) [Enumerable.Take Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) , however, it seems to do what one would expect.

It's not the most efficient solution, either enumerating once to take the elements, then enumerating again to count them, which is unnecessary, or enumerating once to take the elements, then constructing a list in order to get the count property which isn't enumerator-y, as I don't actually want the list.

It's not pretty as I always have to make two assertions, first taking 'x', then checking that I actually received 'x', and it depends upon undocumented behaviour.

Or perhaps I could use:

`bool collectionHasAtLeast2Items = collection.ElementAtOrDefault(2) != null;`

However, that's not semantically-clear.  Maybe the best is to wrap that with a method-name that means what I want.  I'm assuming that this will be efficient, I haven't reflected on the code.

Some other thoughts are using `Last()`, but I explicitly don't want to enumerate through the whole collection.

Or maybe `Skip(2).Any()`, again not semantically completely obvious, but better than `ElementAtOrDefault(2) != null`, though I would think they produce the same result?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not create a collection, load some data, and test?

Comment: The page you link to has a remark `Take<TSource> enumerates source and yields elements until count elements have been yielded or source contains no more elements.` that can be read as "if the source list is shorter than the count, then just that short list is returned"

Comment: @HansKesting - it probably said that until the lawyers got ahold of it :)

Comment: @HansKesting: Yes, probably you're right, thanks.

Comment: By the way, `Take(n).Count()` won't enumerate twice: the `Take` method streams its results lazily, so the most you'd need is a single pass through `n` items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static bool AtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    // Optimization for ICollection<T>
    var genericCollection = source as ICollection<T>;
    if (genericCollection != null)
        return genericCollection.Count >= count;

    // Optimization for ICollection
    var collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null)
        return collection.Count >= count;

    // General case
    using (var en = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (n < count && en.MoveNext()) n++;
        return n == count;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code for general case can be wrapped into a LINQ method, can it not?

Comment: @abatishchev, yes it could, but there's less overhead if you manipulate the enumerator directly (yes, it's a micro-optimization...)

Comment: Then the whole code can be written without LINQ at all, that will be a bit faster, but copyright issue can appear :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good hand-crafted approach, though I think I'll go with `Skip(n).Any()`, as I'd prefer to use the built-in behaviour where I can and that most clearly shows my intent- I think.  `Take()` seems to be faster than `Skip()` however, but that seems a micro-optimisation.

Comment: Reflecting on the `Count()` code, which is very similar to yours, it also adds in a 'checked' statement around the `n++` part.  Also, probably should have a guard (count >= 0).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Count() >= 2`, if you sequence implements `ICollection`?

---

Behind the scene, `Enumerable.Count()` extension method checks does the sequence under loop implements `ICollection`. If it does indeed, `Count` property returned, so target performance should be O(1).

Thus `((IEnumerable<T>)((ICollection)sequence)).Count() >= x` also should have O(1).

Comment: I think he is referring to a higher performance method other than Count().

Comment: I think this is a good method, as given the limitations of `IEnumerable` the best you can hope for in the most general case of that is that you only enumerate two items. Getting optimisation for `ICollection` 'for free' is a nice win.

Comment: @abatishchev, it's O(1) if the collection implements ICollection, but not in the general case. In some cases it might be expensive to perform a full count when you only need to check if there are at least 2 items...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Agree, Kendall's answer uncovers that better.

Comment: I specifically don't want to use `Count()`, as I don't care how many elements are in the collection, and there are likely to be a lot, so counting 10,000, when I'm only interested in the first 2 doesn't seem sensible.  Also they will be `IQueryable`, so I prefer to make the LINQ as efficient as I reasonably can before executing the query.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Count`, but if performance is an issue, you will be better off with `Take`.

```
bool atLeastX = collection.Take(x).Count() == x;
```

Since `Take` (I believe) uses deferred execution, it will only go through the collection once.

abatishchev mentioned that `Count` is O(1) with `ICollection`, so you could do something like this and get the best of both worlds.

```
IEnumerable<int> col;
// set col
int x;
// set x
bool atLeastX;
if (col is ICollection<int>)
{
    atLeastX = col.Count() >= x;
}
else
{
    atLeastX = col.Take(x).Count() == x;
}
```

You could also use `Skip/Any`, in fact I bet it would be even faster than `Take/Count`.

Comment: I always assumed O(1) is as fast as it can get, is it wrong ? (i'm referring the "...it would be even faster" part)

Comment: Updated, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @alex: Actually it will be O(1) + C1 <> O(1) + C2, were C1, C2 are constants, which can be different. So resulting performance is not depended to the number of elements but on underlying code only.

Comment: @abatishchev That's what I mean: I always assumed that, `Count()` being O(1) [+C, ofc], there is no faster way to perform this kind of check. Now I read that `Skip/Any` approach might be even faster, and doubts arise :)

Comment: @KendallFrey:  This was one of my solutions, but I think using `Skip(n).Any()` is much more efficient, and slightly clearer about the meaning.  I am reluctant to use `Count()` except in situations where I actually care how many elements are in the enumeration.